# PHP arrays memory usage

Tags: php, arrays, memory

I am trying to find a way to map big amount of strings to ints. I tried it using arrays and found a behaviour that I don't understand. When I index arrays by strings (array('someStirng' => 1)) it consumes less memory than vice versa (array(1 => 'someString')). Does it mean, that it's better to index arrays by strings and leave ints as values for big amount of string-int pairs or what's the catch? Why there is so big memory allocation difference?

```
function gen() {
    static $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Indexing by strings - returns 490 KB

```
$a = array();

for($x = 0;$x < 100000;$x++){
    $a[gen()]  = $x;
}


echo (memory_get_usage() / 1024) . ' KB';
```

Indexing by ints - returns 10790.2890625 KB (~22 times more than first case, but same ammount of information stored!)

```
$a = array();

for($x = 0;$x < 100000;$x++){
    $a[$x]  = gen();
}


echo (memory_get_usage() / 1024) . ' KB';
```

Comment: Using `rand()` in bechmarking is usually not a recipe for comparable results.

Also, [`memory_get_usage()`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) returns the *current* memory usage. An eager garbage collector *could* have already gotten to some of the memory by the time you check the usage. Can you repeat the experiment without the `rand()` and with [`memory_get_peak_usage()`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)? Maybe you could even try both `false` and `true` as parameters to compare actual and 'emalloc-only' memory.

Comment: Can you print out the size of the array at the end of each example? Your `gen()` function might generate the same string twice, resulting in that string array index being overwritten instead of adding a new item, meaning a smaller array.

Comment: If you consider that 100,000 * 8 bytes is around 780KB then it should be glaringly obvious that the `memory_get_usage()` function isn't telling you what you think it is OR the size of those two arrays aren't what you think they are.  I'd lay money on the former.

Comment: @TomasCreemers  
I don't think rand() is the problem. I am using rand() in both cases, but in second case, when I am indexing by integers, it always allocates ~22 times bigger amount of memory. Yes, it could generate some string twice or more times, but there are 63^8 possible combinations and I am generating just 100.000 (for comparsion purposes, it's "just" 63^2.7788) strings and the probablity is just too low to disrupt my test results. memory_geat_peak_usage() returns the same number + few more KBs in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I repeat your experiments using your code, I get 18 072 000 bytes for the integer indexes and 16 471 960 bytes for the string indexes. Not much difference, which can be attributed to different memory management for array keys and their values.

Using `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` instead produces very similar results. Calculating the difference in memory usage right before and right after the for loop, I get 18 087 936 bytes with integer indexes and 16 515 072 bytes with string indexes.

That's a small difference which could be explained by different internal memory management for array keys and for array values. Perhaps since array keys are limited to scalars and array values aren't, PHP can optimize somewhere.

In any case, like @ed-heal said, use the best data structure for whatever you're trying to do. The memory usage is probably not *that* important and if it is, PHP might not be the tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get your results? Why they are so different from mine? I even tried memory_get_peak_usage(true), but the result are same than before, just rounded to powers of 2

Comment: When I test your code on http://codepad.org/vwhCDVSf (with `memory_get_usage()` exactly like in your code), I get 9150.54296875 KB for integer keys and 7978.8125 KB for string keys. Using `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` I get 9216 KB for integer keys and 8192 KB for string keys. I really can't seem to reproduce the huge differences you are observing.

Comment: Well at least, for future I will know that my local server does not work very good with PHP memory usages functions. (Win XP + XAMPP)

Comment: Perhaps XAMPP installed an old PHP version or odd configuration? If you're this interested in memory usage, you may want to compare with a version downloaded from http://php.net/ .

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
```

has 8 times to do its business

Where as this loop

```
for($x = 0;$x < 100000;$x++){
```

Does it a little more!

Now let me think where the problem is ...

**EDIT**

Just noticed that the sands have shifted.

Use whatever data structure is appropriate for the task in hand.